# Read HTTP Status Code from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, http-status-codes

I am uploading a file to the server. To do that I am using the SOAP Web Service that the developers of the site created.

This service `CustomerWebService` contains only one void method `transferFile`. In about 20-30 seconds after the upload I am getting the confirmation email from the site.

It works fine, however I would like to get at least HTTP 200 status right after the execution (like I see in Fiddler right away.)

How can I return one in code?

```
 public ActionResult UploadFile(string fileName)
 {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();

        CustomerWebService ws = new CustomerWebService ();
        ws.transferFile("user", "password", line);
        return Json("{Success}", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: You show how to send the JSON but not how you receive it.  How you receive it determines how we can suggest to get the HTTP Status Code rather than the JSON, no?

Comment: try/catch SoapException and WebException

Comment: A failure HTTP code will throw an exception, so like @jgauffin says, you just need to handle this and return a "non-success" Json response.

Comment: To user1477388: The method is actually "void", it does not return anything. I would read the resonce if I coud.

Comment: To Liam, jgauffin: Thank you, guys. But I would like to return 200 as well. I want to allow user to upload series of files.